# Java framework/library to easily add helpdesk functionality in an existing web application

Tags: java, help-desk

In a JSF-based legacy web application I have to develop very simple help desk functionality.

I'm looking for a java framework which can speed the work but after a long search I found nothing, only few products in .NET technology. Can you suggest something ?

Lots of free help desk software are available but don't think it is a good idea to use one of them side by side with the legacy application because I would have make deep changes in the help desk software in order to integrate it (with potential license problems too).

So what I really need is a middleware/framework/library where I can pick up some modules and glue them with my business logic.

At the moment the requirements are very simple:

- track the request from users
- ask clarifications when needed
- perform the necessary actions
- save some notes.

It is not too difficult to implement from scratch but soon I will be asked for improvements so I looking for something which can meet future demands