# Java Open source Help desk software

Tags: java

Refining a previous [unanswered question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/java-framework-library-for-easily-add-help-desk-functionality-in-an-existing-web) with a no more appropriate title
I'm looking for help desk software with the following requisites:

- java language
- Open source
- Mysql support
- Multi-language
- easy e-mail integration
- look and feel easily configurable via template
- maintained and alive project

Till now I only found iTracker, but it seems a bit limited.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can find a nice list of options at http://helpdeskreviews.com/open-source-helpdesks.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracking issues(Your title was a little confusing, but from the `iTracker` example I figured that you are looking for an issue-tracker) and the requirement that the software needs to be in `java` language, the most known software is definitely [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira).

- It supports multilanguage, [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Choosing+a+Language)
- Mysql support, [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+MySQL)
- Look and feel configuration, [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Customizing+the+Look+and+Feel)

Definitely maintained and alive, actually most open-source projects I follow use JIRA.

Open source but not entirely, check the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) article.

And a screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Example: A client makes a complain about a missing item in your website so he creates an issue(ticket) in Jira and says "Filippo, where are my multi-billion dollars products in the main page?" and he passes you the issue.
 
then you assign this issue to somebody responsible for that and
 
then he resolves it back to the client who 
then closes it because it's fixed now.

The whole process is monitored through Jira with details.

P.S I was confused by the title because a Help Desk implementation generally is a ticket system which is usually an issue tracking system like JIRA, your question was fine really :)

Comment: Perhaps I need some interaction with other people in order to explain better my needs. In reality there are no 'issues' to track, but they are requests from users. Most of these requests contains data related to my specific domain and sometimes they need to be integrated/corrected and everything should be tracked and tidy. About your suggestion on Jira I had already checked that product, it is not open source, at least not completely and above all you have to pay for it. I forgot to explicitly mention another requisite I have, it must be free for commercial use too.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if the example I mentioned matches your needs, you are looking for a ticket system-> issue tracker system, but I am not sure if a Java based system now covers all your needs(free for commercial use), will it be okay if it isn't based in java?

Comment: Jira is not open source. It's commercial. With commercial or academic license you can peek at its source, but it does not fit the open source definition.